# PHP passing object property as method parameter

Tags: php, function, methods

.Hello! I'm trying to figure why I can't use

```
$myCar = get_path_from_letter($car->letter);
```

Where get_path_from_letter uses a switch to return a string depending on the letter passed:

```
$car->get_path_from_letter = function($letter){
     $path = "";
switch($letter){
 case 'a':
$path = $car->A;
break;

case'b':
$path = $car->B;
break;
}
return $path;
};
```

If anyone could explain where I'm going wrong or offer a pointer for which direction to go to it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: 1. Please post the exact error message you get 2. Are you assigning a anonymous function to a class property ? 3. `$myCar = get_path_from_letter($car->letter);` If it is in a class is this call outside or inside the class definition? (Just show us your **full** code)

Comment: Is `$car` inside the scope of the function?

Comment: Your anonymous function has no idea that `$car` even exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about guessing what the problem might be without any problem description or even an attempt at an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in $car via use:

```
$car->get_path_from_letter = function($letter) use ($car){
    $path = "";
    switch($letter){
        case 'a':
            $path = $car->A;
            break;
        case'b':
            $path = $car->B;
            break;
    }
    return $path;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, you read my mind! Couldn't remember the magic word lol.

Comment: Glad to help. Why do you have this as an anonymous function, though? Why not define it in the class itself?

Comment: Friend asked me, thought I had remembered doing something like this but it has been a while since I've used PHP.

Comment: If you're ever reusing that code, you'll want to put that function into the class itself instead. Otherwise, you have to declare it for every instance of that $car class you create.

Comment: Okay, that's prob what he is going to have to end up doing. But at least for now he will be able to test a few things. Thanks again!